# Hazelcast Trylock and multiple calls

Tags: java, hazelcast

I ran into the following issue:

We have a multipart Process *P* with two steps (*s1* and *s2*).
The process is implemented, that in *s1* a lock is acquired - but not released. In *s2* the lock is required again (?) and after *s2* is done, the lock is released again.

From the [documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/lock.html):

> Locks are re-entrant: the same thread can lock multiple times on the same lock. Note that for other threads to be able to require this lock, the owner of the lock must call unlock as many times as the owner called lock.

If I understand this correctly, this means, if I call *s1* for the first time, the lock is acquired by a Thread from the threadpool, say *Tx*. Since the lock is not released after the request, the thread goes back to the pool. If a second request comes in, the lock is in use (by *Tx*). But if I start enough requests, at some point in time, I will get *Tx* from the pool again, and I am able to successfully *tryLock* the same lock as before again?

Is this right? This means, the lock is not exclusive for it's lifetime, or only insofar exclusive, that it is exclusively bound to one thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lock has the concept of lock ownership; which means that there is a particular thread is owning a lock. It also means that only this thread needs to release this lock.

So your usecase where thread1 acquires and thread2 releases, will not work with a lock (no matter if it a hz lock or a regular j.u.c.l.ReentrantLock).

You might want to have a look at the ISemaphore and initialise it with 1, so you can create a binary semaphore. This will allow you to acquire a 'lock' in 1 thread and release the 'lock' in another.

However, it will not deal with reentrant behavior. But will deadlock instead.

Comment: Yes. You verify my assumptions. The implementation was wrong. And that explains the weird behaviour, that although one user locked the lock, another was able to acquire the lock - because threads are pooled and the reentrant behaviour, which allowed the same thread acquiring the lock again. Regarding the ISemaphore: Thank you for the tip.

Comment: For what we are doing, I think, if I'm getting it right ISemaphore isn't the right choice. What is needed is a) a Lock which prevents other users from starting the process and (more complicated) b) the possibility, that the user, which acquired the lock is identified across several requests and c) other requests are simply rejected. If I get it right, ISemaphore queues the requests and is not able to identify the user. I am thinking about a Map, storing a UUID and a timestamp (to prevent long lasting deadlocks).

Comment: If you only acquire exclusive access, and not blocking, then you might want to have a look at the IAtomicReference using the compareAndSet method. 

But I guess an IMap could do the trick as well since it can provide similar semantics with replace(key, old, new) method.

Comment: Oh, okay! Thank you very much! Yes, IAtomicReference does exactly what is needed, since only _one_ Lock is needed at this moment.